# ajax call on google chart from option select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

A user is able to search a gene in a gene database. The database then returns subtypes of this gene. The subtypes are then dynamically loaded into option selects.
When a user clicks a subtype from the option select, the chart has to plot. But I can't figure out why it doesn't. Guessing that my ajax call isn't done properly but I can't find the problem.
[image]

The data comes through in the alert. However the google chart does not plot :(

**Code**

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#selectinput").change(function(){ 
      var input = $(this).val(); 
      var dataString = "selectinput="+input;
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawchart);

      function drawchart(){
      $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "get-data.php", 
        data: dataString, 
        success: function(result){ 
          var res = result.slice(2, -2);
          var str = res.replace(/["]/g, "");
          alert(str); //alert the right data!
          var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([str]);
          //apparently this doesn't work

        var options = {
        title: 'Transcriptome',
        hAxis: { ticks: [1, {v:2, f:'Layer 2/3'}, {v:3, f:'Layer 4'}, 4] },
        vAxis: {title: 'MEAN'},
        bubble: {textStyle: {fontSize: 11}},
        sizeAxis: {maxSize: 30, minSize: 15},
        bubble: {textStyle: {color: 'none'}}

      };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('serieschart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);


        }
      });
      }

    });
  });
</script>

<div id="serieschart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Help much appreciated!
EDIT: I'm not talking about the chart which already plotted.
It has to plot a new one below the option select which it doesn't right now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add in your ajax request:

```
dataType:'json'
```

in success change to:

`var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result);`

Comment: doesn't change the output. still thanks for your reply

Comment: I don't know but are you sure that:
`[str]`
is two dimensional array?
because i think its string inside [] and this maybe the problem
arrayToDataTable expect two dimensional array as first parameter

Comment: `jQuery.parseJSON('[[111,222],[111,333]]');` 

`str = jQuery.parseJSON(results);`

`new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(str);`

Comment: str is alerted as you can see in the image. it's a string with multiple arrays.